# Draw all lines obtained with HoughLines in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

I'm using OpenCV 3.2.

I'd like to extract and draw all lines in this image.

[image]

For this, I first obtain the contours of the image. For example, I'm using the [Canny](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga04723e007ed888ddf11d9ba04e2232de) algorithm, with a double threshold 100 (low) and 200 (high).

```
Mat image = cv::imread(<image_path>, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
cv::Mat contours;
cv::Canny(image, contours, 100, 200);
```

[image: Canny]

Then, I call the [HoughLines](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga46b4e588934f6c8dfd509cc6e0e4545a) function with a resolution of 1 pixel and π / 45 radians. I just want those lines which have a length of at least 60 pixels.

```
std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines;
cv::HoughLines(canny, lines, 1, CV_PI/45, 60);
```

This returns me a vector `lines` with the rho `p` and theta `θ` parameters in the Hough space of the desired lines. As we know, the line going through a contour pixel `(x_i, y_i)` is:

```
p = x_i cos(θ) + y_i sin(θ)
```

We know `p` and `θ`, so we know all the pixels in this line. Two easy points to calculate are `A` with `x_i = 0` and `B` with `y_i = 0`.

```
A = (0, p / sin(θ))
B = (p / cos(θ), 0)
```

Let's draw them with the [line](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga7078a9fae8c7e7d13d24dac2520ae4a2) function in blue color.

```
cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_GRAY2BGR);
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
    float p = lines[i][0];
    float theta = lines[i][1];
    cv::Point a(0, static_cast<int>(p / std::sin(theta)));
    cv::Point b(static_cast<int>(p / std::cos(theta)), 0);
    cv::line(image, a, b, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0));
}
```

[image: Lines]

The result is that it only draws me 6 lines, of a total of 14 obtained. As you can see, only those lines that intersect the row 0 and column 0 of the image are drawn. What is the same, those lines which have `A` and `B` points in the image boundary. The rest of the lines have these points outside the image.

How can I achieve to draw all the lines in an easy way? I can calculate all the pixels of the obtained lines and draw them (we know them), but I'd like to draw them by minimizing lines of code and using OpenCV api.

Comment: There's an [example in the doc](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) on how to draw those lines

Comment: @Miki I saw it, but I didn't understand it. I don't get that magic number 1000. That's the reason of my question, I'd like to understand that code before using it (or find another way to draw the lines).

Comment: It's just a big number, to be sure that your 2 points are _outside_ of the image,so that you draw a line that passes through all your image.

Comment: @Miki But with my solution, the not drawn lines also have two defined points (1. both inside the image, 2. one inside and one outside, 3. both outside). What's the explanation so that the example in the doc draws all lines, and my example not? `Line` function must receive both points outside the image?

Comment: Because the lines with the other slope (from top left to bottom right) don't intersect with y axis inside the image. You're drawing them, but you can't see them

Comment: Ok, one mistake is that lines can be horizontal or vertical, and thus, they won't cross row 0 or column 0, respectively. In mathematically terms, we have a division by 0 with sin(θ) and cos(θ).

Comment: @Miki I understand it now! Thank you